# Permalink structure for custom post/custom taxonomy with page slug prefix

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type and custom taxonomy:

```
register_post_type( 'faq',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'FAQ' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'FAQ-Eintrag' ),
            'add_new' => __('Neuer FAQ-Eintrag')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'query_var' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'faq','with_front' => false),
        'supports' => array(
            'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'
          ),
    )
);

register_taxonomy(
    'faq-kategorie',        // internal name = machine-readable taxonomy name
    'faq',      // object type = post, page, link, or custom post-type
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'FAQ – Kategorie',   // the human-readable taxonomy name
          'query_var' => true,  // enable taxonomy-specific querying
          'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'faq-category' )   
        )
    );
```

I have a page where i show all custom faq posts, this page has slug
/faq/

My intention is to have permalinks with this structure:

> /faq/ - overview faq page (page with template)
>
> /faq/slug-of-faq-kategorie/slug-of-faq-custom-post - single faq post
>
> /faq/slug-of-faq-kategorie/ - faq term archive

When I set 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'faq' ) for taxonomy i get 404 for taxonomy/post

Always had problems with this (becuase first slug of page is faq=same slug for post/taxonomy). Can anyone help with this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To get `/faq/` as an overview page: archive-faq.php

- in the register post type, you will want to add : `has_archive` which is defaulted to false (see [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type))

To ensure you are really able to see the result of your permalink changes, please click `save permalinks` in the wp-admin settings permalinks to "refresh" the cache.

Comment: Thanks but its not what im asking - im asking how to add rewrite rules to be able to show given permalink structure (without 404).